# A single word for someone who is quick to hate others

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

What is a single word to describe someone who is quick to hate others?

With anger we can say *quick-tempered*, but what about quick in hating other people/easily hates others.

*Hateful* means full of hate, but doesn't really give the meaning of being quick to hate people.

Comment: IMO, It's hard to imagine a quick switch from liking (or not knowing/caring) to hating without anger, fear or perhaps disgust being involved. Is it really possible to be quick-to-hate except by being prone to these fight/flight emotions? I assume quick-to-hate is different to the ambient level of hatred for everyone ever/never met.

Comment: Do you mean a person who also hates his fellows and family e.t.c. or some one who dislike/hate any new person he met with? Is it about a person who just dislike and avoid or who hate and try to hurt others?

Answer (score 51):

**Misanthrope**: defined by [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misanthrope) as "a person who hates or distrusts humankind."  It may be too broad for your need, but if you mean to say that the person harbors an angry, resentful hatred for his/her fellow man/woman, this word might be what you're looking for.

Comment: +1 As the word popped to mind, I saw your answer. 100% correct term.

Comment: +1 - I saw the question under "hot questions" on another SE site. I thought "misanthrope" and sure enough, you got it right.

Comment: It does not necessarily mean anger and resentfulness. See some elaboration [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/102069/21458), and note that Arthur Schopenhauer, according to [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misanthropy), while misanthropic in many of his ideas (such as his anti-natalistic views), thought that ethical treatment of fellow human is still a way to go. If humanity is a “mistake”, it does not follow one must hate it.

Answer (score 34):

**Malevolent** (or *malicious*, which is close) may do it: *wishing evil or harm to another or others; showing ill will; ill-disposed; malicious*

**Ill-disposed** itself would also be good. Someone who is ill-disposed towards others has a tendency to dislike them.

**Hostile** and **antagonistic** can be used to describe people who act aggressively, treating others as if they are (potential) enemies.

Comment: I'm not sure *malevolent* fits, but I like all your other suggestions, so `+1` from me.

Comment: Fair enough, though ill-disposed is a synonym granted it by dictionary.com, not just by me.

Comment: It has connotations to me of evilness, more than hostility. I suppose the two are related.

Answer (score 17):

A person that hates is a hater.

Recently I've noticed that this word has taken on an implication that the hater is predisposed to it.

***[Haters gonna hate](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/haters-gonna-hate)***

Comment: I don't think that the phrase intends to imply that they're predisposed to hating, rather that they always will hate.

Comment: I think it's generally safe to assume that if someone's asking for a word here, they want standard English, not trashy slang.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill: I don’t think it’s fair to call “hater” an example of trashy slang. It’s hardly even slang: *-er* is one of the most productive suffixes in English, and “hater” is quite literally “one who hates”.

Comment: Actually, that word sense is consistent with current usage in the American dialect. It is used quite frequently among educated people and will likely be included in a regular dictionary very shortly. However I agree it would not yet be appropriate if one wanted to set an academic tone.

Comment: Hmmm. It might be used *ironically* among some educated people, but I would say that any unironic use still marks the speaker as unsophisticated. Opinions on these things might vary, but I'm *really* not ready to see that threshold crossed.

Comment: That is really nothing more than an [Ad-Hominim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hominem) attack while they are popular they are still fallacies.

Comment: The problem with the term "hater" is that it specifies no object of hatred, and thus does not agree in a grammatical sense with the root verb "to hate", which takes an object (mandatorily). As a result, I agree that many see it as a particularly uneducated figure of speech, and certainly not something belonging in a dictionary as it flies in the face of basic English grammatical convention.

Comment: My judgment is that 'haters' has entered the casual mainstream - you can use it in the office, but not in your academic publication.

Comment: I upvoted this because I think it's a useful, *increasingly* mainstream term, and because I love the bemonocled tone of your paraphrasing of the statement "hater's gon' hate."  Good show! :) [Hater's gon' hate](http://gimmebar-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/4e26eff8d76f2.jpg)

Comment: So many "hater" haters in these comments.

Comment: Fish gotta swim.  Birds gotta fly.  Skiers gotta ski.  Informal language users gotta informally use language.

Answer (score 3):

[Bigot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigot_%28disambiguation%29), "a prejudiced person who is intolerant of any opinions differing from their own or intolerant of people [who are different]".

Generally someone who hates quickly does so based on one of the factors of bigotry.

Comment: I'm not sure if this fits quite exactly. I can imagine someone who is quick to hate others that even hold the same opinions or worldview.

Comment: @DuckMaestso The question doesn't say why the person hates the others, just that they hate quickly. A bigot may hate quickly as soon as they spot the other doesn't share their worldview.

Comment: @Hugo, fair point, but "The question doesn't say why the person hates the others" is precisely why I think this answer is too narrow.

Answer (score 3):

Hows about **[judgemental](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/judgemental)**, while it means quick to judge in general rather than quick to hate specifically it does tend to be used more in a negative conotation.

Comment: Or *judgmental*, for purists :L

Comment: it actually started as judgmental but my browser's dictionary preferred judgemental, might be a US/UK thing? as a brit working in an american company I am so confused >.<

Answer (score 2):

**Hate-hasty**, or just **hatesty** for short

(ok I just made that up, but no-one criticises Shakespere for doing that - it's not fair)

Comment: Neologismicity is an important tradition in English writing, and is actually very common in most of the world's languages. New words tend to take some time to establish themselves, and many fade away after a short while.

Comment: Is 'Neologismicity' a real word :-)

Comment: @JackDouglas, it's ok for Shakespeare to invent new words because he wrote a lot of appealing plays.

Comment: Actually, we don't know how many words Shakespeare invented - he wrote down a lot of words at a time when not that many people were writing things that have been preserved to this day.

Answer (score 2):

**Unforgiving** would apply to someone who can't overlook mistakes and easily judges negatively.

Answer (score 2):

How about *intolerant* ?  suggests a lack of patience and an unwillingness to accept others.

Answer (score 1):

The word I would use is **inflammable,** someone who is easily "inflamed" against others.

Answer (score 1):

A **[prejudiced](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/dict.aspx?word=prejudiced)** person has an "irrational suspicion or hatred of a particular group, race, or religion."

However, W.C. Fields joked:

> I am free of all prejudice. I hate everyone equally.

Comment: I would rather say **judgmental** than prejudiced, but the question seems to be for a one-word answer (i.e. noun)...

Comment: @Andrew If anything, it seems to be asking for one describing word, an adjective: "single word to describe..." "With anger we can say quick-tempered..." "Hateful..."

Comment: Good point, yes the examples in the question are adjectives too.